# Dependent variable in grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-variable

I have a custom variable in grafana `$var`, which has values `["option1", "option2", "option3"]`. I would like to have another custom (hidden) variable `$auxvar` where the value is entirely dependent on the value of `$var`, e.g.:

```
"option1" -> "auxvar_option1"
"option2" -> "auxvar_option2"
"option3" -> "auxvar_option3"
```

Because the value of `$auxvar` is entirely dependent on `$var`, I want the user to be able to select the value of `$var` and have `$auxvar` set automatically (without the user's knowledge). I currently just have two custom variables `$var` and `$auxvar`, where the user must set both, but this is a somewhat hacky workaround. It seems like chained variables are almost related here, but they don't quite fit my use case. I'm wondering if there's some obvious way to do this that I'm missing.

Edit: realize this is ambiguous. I should clarify that `$auxvar` is not directly related to the content of `$var` as the above implies. It's more like this:

```
label1 -> label2="blah2", label3="blah3"
label2 -> label1="blah1", label3="blah3"
label3 -> label1="blah1", label2="blah2"
```

I basically have a query that averages by `$var`, but based on the selection of that label, I want to limit the result set using `$auxvar`.

Comment: Why you don't just use "auxvar_$var" instead?

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira sorry, original question was ambiguous. Hopefully the edit clarifies things a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use key/value variables like the following example:

```
Type                      = Custom
Values separated by comma = var1 : auxvar1,var2 : auxvar2, var3 : auxvar3
```

The user will just see one picklist:

[image]

But you'll have the key and the value available in your panels, for example, suppose the user select "var1":

```
${var:text}  = var1
${var:value} = auxvar1
```